# export multiple classes typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have a protractor project, where I want to export multiple classes from another project into my test class. The first class of `Helper` imports ok, but for the rest, I get an error: `has no exported member - People, Groups`

---

#### sub-project code

app.ts

```
export { Helper } from './src/helpers/helper';
export { People } from './src/helpers/people';
export { Groups } from './src/helpers/groups';
```

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "name": "sub-project",
  "main": "app.ts",
  ...
}
```

helper.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from './http-client';
export class Helper {
  private httpClient = new HttpClient();
    public async myFunction():  { }
}
```

people.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from './http-client';
export class People {
  private httpClient = new HttpClient();
    public async myFunction(): { }
}
```

#### main-project code

test.ts

```
import { Helper, People, Groups} from 'sub-project'; // error, has no exported member - People, Groups, (Helper - ok)
```

tsconfig

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "lib",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "types": [
            "chai",
            "chai-as-promised",
            "mocha"
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Also, do you have any .d.ts files or anything for sub-project? I'm wondering if test.ts is referencing out-of-date typings or something.

Comment: no d.ts files in the project

Comment: Show your `people`file. I think you don't export class in a proper way in this file.

Comment: have updated example to show Helper.ts and People.ts

Comment: That's weird! I can't reproduce the issue. Maybe if you should include your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Immediate re-exports is a new feature and might be buggy. Have you tried `import { Helper } from './src/helpers/helper'; export { Helper }`?

Comment: have now included tsconfig above

Comment: @NinoFiliu Thanks, that solved it!

`import { Helper } from './src/helpers/helper'; export { Helper }`

Comment: Great! As per the recommendation of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat) post, I shall copy my comment in the answer section and you shall accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immediate re-exports is a new feature and might be buggy.

Avoid

```
export { Helper } from './src/helpers/helper';
export { People } from './src/helpers/people';
export { Groups } from './src/helpers/groups';
```

and use the following instead:

```
import { Helper } from './src/helpers/helper';
import { People } from './src/helpers/people';
import { Groups } from './src/helpers/groups';
export { Helper, People, Groups };
```