# Import, rename, and export a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

With JavaScript what's the shortest way to import a named export, rename it, and export it again?

This code works but it feels more verbose than it should be

```
import { mock as myFunctionMock } from 'context/myFunction';
export const myFunction = myFunctionMock;
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why would you want that?

Comment: @Vencovsky I was just thinking the same thing! I could only think wrapping a massive read-only project function but even then...

Comment: @Vencovsky the renaming or the shortness? The renaming could be really useful - let's say you've made some algorithm and export it as "calculateFoo" but then find a library that has it as "calculateBar" - instead of changing your entire source code, you can just re-export and rename it to "calculateFoo". Or you could just always be re-exporting it from the start but changing where you import it from.

Comment: @VLAZ isn't easier to just rename it in the file you import it?

Comment: @Vencovsky so go through your entire codebase and change every import of `myFunctions` to `externalLibrary` and `calculateFoo` to `calculateBar` and then every time you use `calculateFoo` in your actual code you have to change it to `calculateBar`? Sure, you can do that. I don't think it's easier than NOT doing all of that and changing a single line.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh now I see

Comment: @Vencovsky you could be authoring your own library but reusing a function from a library you didn't write

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can combine the import and export like so:

```
export { mock as myFunctionMock } from 'context/myFunction';
```

See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Note that you won't actually be able to *use* `myFunctionMock` within your code file since you haven't imported it. Neither `mock` nor `myFunctionMock` will be defined within *this* module.

This is a useful shorthand when you're building a library that will be used by other modules or by your end-user.

For example, if you had a `utils` library that you wanted to export, but you wanted to organize your util functions across several smaller files, such as `stringUtils`, `objectUtils`, `dataUtils`, etc, you can export the contents of those modules within your `utils` module to create a single, monolithic access point:

**stringUtils.js**

```
export function toLower(){}

export function toUpper(){}
```

**objectUtils.js**

```
export function propertyMap(){}
```

**utils.js**

```
export {
    toLower as stringToLower,
    toUpper as stringToUpper,
} from "stringUtils.js";
export {
    propertyMap as objectPropertyMap
} from "objectUtils.js";
```

I wouldn't generally recommend this approach for internal code as it can make your dependency trees a bit wonky in some cases. It can, however, be extremely useful in situations where you want to import from a common interface but the implementation is dependent on the build (prod vs dev, web vs node, etc)

Comment: Also it's supposed to work according to the specs, [some bugs have been reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302925) when using that syntax

Comment: I think the bugginess is unique to Typescript. Webpack has, in my experience, handled this without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { mock as myFunction } from 'context/myFunction';
export { myFunction };
```

Comment: Hi! While this may be an answer to the question (untested), code only answers are discouraged on SO. Please consider adding an explanation to your answer to help OP better understand, and to provide greater benefit to future visitors of the site. Thanks!

Comment: @d_kennetz yeah, my fault... Will do in future comments, thanks!

Comment: @JDB I don't think my example is using a default export... Are you sure?

Comment: This is a good choice if you want to both export `myFunction` and also *use* `myFunction` within the module. It's better than redeclaring a constant.

Comment: @JDB ok, I see! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

in your original exporter, do:

```
module.exports = { mock: function () {...}}
```

When importing, do:

```
const myFunctionMock = require('file path of exporter');
```

then to reexport in the same file:

```
module.exports = {renamedMock: myFunctionMock};
```

Now any changes to `mock` will propagate to the other modules where it's referenced (side note, this is node.js in a nutshell).